# Authentication on facebook for graph api

Tags: facebook, notifications, token

i need to get my facebook notifications. So i find this: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fnotifications

if i understand well i need to get a token and go to https://graph.facebook.com/me/notifications/ to get an array of all my notifications.
But i can't understand how i can get a corrent token. 
Someone can help me? :)

Comment: whats your programming language ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate using Facebook Connect first.

This is probably where you should start reading.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/